# VWD can't create SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-web-developer

When I attempt to add a SQL Server database to a website project (via add new items), I get the following error:

[image]

> "Connections to SQL Server database
>   files (.mdf) require SQL Server 2005
>   Express or SQL Server 2008 Express to
>   be installed and running on the local
>   computer. The current version can be
>   downloaded from..."

This is despite having installed SQL SErver Express 2008 - and seeing it running under services.

A number of other instances of SQL have been on the machine in the past although they have been uninstalled.

I have tried reinstalling SQL & VWD several times to no avail.

Comment: Can you post the **textual** error messages, please?? This screenshot is nearly impossible to read....

Comment: Sorry, I thought the image clickable.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem? I having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "SQL Server Instance Name" which is setup in:

Tools --> Options --> Database Tools --> DataConnections

Verify that the instance name matches your SQL08 instance.